# Autocorrelations using vDSP functions

Tags: c++, macos, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

Given a 1D vector of floats or doubles, how can the autocorrelations for that vector be calculated using functions from the vDSP library in the Accelerate Framework?

One would suspect the vDSP_acor() and vDSP_acorD() functions would perform this calculation, but the documentation vDSP_Library.pdf (available [here](http://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/ve/downloads/vDSP_Library.pdf)) doesn't do a very good job explaining how the function arguments are used.

Similarly, the vDSP_conv() and vDSP_convD() functions mention the ability to perform correlations and convolutions between two vectors, but don't provide enough explanation or example code for me to be able to use them successfully.  For example, if a filter kernel is used to convolve a 2D matrix, I would imagine two calls to vDSP_convD() would be needed, with different values of signalStride, but this is omitted from the documentation.  Another omission is how the data in the filter must be packed.  If padded with zeros, does it matter if the zeros come first, last, or do they need to be evenly distributed on either side of the non-zero entries?  Are there requirements for filter length, result length and input length?

Suggestions for a useful examples:  Implementation of autocorrelation of a vector with itself using both vDSP_acor() and vDSP_conv().  Dyadic multiplication of two arrays in the frequency domain that are packed as real data that has been forward FFT'd using vDSP_fft2d_zrip() that would be used in the calculation of an autocorrelation function before the IFT returns the un-normalized answer.  Implementation of a gaussian kernel convolutionon a 1D and 2D array.  Generally this is a fantastic library (can you say FAST?!), but I've found these particular functions a bit hard to understand, and the aforementioned examples would probably be widely used because they are so common in signal processing and image analysis.

Suggestions for maintainers of the vDSP_Library reference document: I assume "spatial domain" and "time domain" are equivalent throughout the document.  If not, please do make that distinction.  Also, please check that any formulas have well-defined parameters that match the declared names of arguments in the functions being discussed.

Footnote: here the autocorrelation I refer to is defined by: A[T] = <(X[t]-m)(X[t-T]-m)>/v, where A[T] is the autocorrelation at lag T, t is the index of the signal X, m is the average of X over all t, v is the variance of X over all t, and the angle brackets <> indicate an average over all available pairs of X's that are T apart.

Answer (score 9):

The documentation for `vDSP_acorD` seems reasonably clear to me, if a little sparse, and there does appear to be a typo in the parameter descriptions.

```
void vDSP_acorD (double * A,
    double * C, int N, int M);
```

`A` is the input signal, `C` is the autocorrelation output, `N` is the number of samples in `A`, and `M` is the number of output values that you require in `C` (i.e. C will hold lag values from `0` to `M - 1`).

If `vDSP_acorD` is not available then you may be able to use `vDSP_conv` since convolution is the same operation as correlation with one of the input signals reversed.

Alternatively you can roll your own fast autocorrelation using the fact that autocorrelation is equivalent to the inverse FFT of the power spectrum, so:

```
auto_correlation = IFFT(MAG(FFT(x)))
```

where

```
FFT = forward FFT
IFFT = inverse FFT
MAG = magnitude of complex spectrum (sqrt(re * re + im * im))
```

and then use the FFT routines from vDSP.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  Your interpretation of `vDSP_acorD` seems reasonable.  For the convolution, it seems that by default it actually might do the correlation, and you have to specify a stride of -1 and pass the last element of the filter to the function to actually do a convolution.  But there are other things about the convolution documentation that make it harder to use in general (say, for doing a convolution of a gaussian kernel).

Comment: @oldmanjank: OK - I haven't actually looked at the convolution routines in any detail, but if you just want autocorrelation then you may as well just use `vDSP_acorD`. This also has the advantage that it will automatically select a time domain or frequency domain implementation depending on the size of `M`, in order to give you the best performance.

Comment: Ouch! Here's a kicker: vDSP_acor and vDSP_acorD aren't actually declared in any of the vecLib headers in version vecLib-268.0, which came out last year.

Comment: Oh dear - looks like you may have to use `vDSP_conv` after all. You can of course roll your own autocorrelation routine quite easily - I'll add to my answer above.

Comment: Many thanks, Paul.  No need to spend time rolling a general autocorrelation function, that is easy enough indeed.

Comment: Oh, but what would be useful here, and going WAY above and beyond the call of duty, would be an autocorrelation function that operates on the trickily-packed data that results from call to vDSP_fft2d_zrip(), which is the 2D real in-place DFT.  Because a 1D is applied twice (horizontally then vertically), but the nyquist frequencies are stored in the second element, doing the element-wise multiplication isn't trivial, especially if when the data structure is a DSPSplitComplex!

Comment: @oldmanjank: sorry, I meant to say rolling a fast autocorrelation routine using the FFT routines in vDSP - see above.

Comment: @oldmanjank: ah - you want **2D** autocorrelation - I hadn't guessed that form the question but probably should have - life gets a little trickier then. The `vDSP_acor` routine wouldn't have helped you either way then, since it appears to be 1D only.

Comment: Haha!  Well, we shouldn't have to guess at what people mean, either here on SO or within the vDSP documentation: I could have been clearer. Still, having access to the 1D `DSP_acor()` would have been nice for other things I'm doing.  Sigh.  I really appreciate your quick and helpful replies.  I'll go play around with the convolution functions and submit a couple bug reports to the Apple folk and maybe I'll have some more specific, less open-ended questions on here soon.

Comment: @oldmanjank: OK - I wish you luck. I normally keep an eye out for FFT and DSP-related questions here on SO so I'll look out for any subsequent questions from you.